# SSH Encoding in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, encoding, ssh, utf-8, debian

i'm using windows with powershell on my local pc and debian on my remote server.

I installed `scoop install openssh` ([scoop](https://github.com/lukesampson/scoop) is an easy package installer for windows).

When I want to send some UTF-8 characters from my local pc with windows I only receive gibberish characters like `â-?` instead of `●` on my remote PC. As seen in the screenshot (Putty has an option to set utf-8, but i want to use powershell)

I'm sure that is because of my server uses utf-8 and my pc iso-xyz. How can i change my local encoding? or is it a better way to change remotes encoding for that session?

[image]

Comment: Please try next 7-step procedure: 1. open `cmd` window; 2. change `cmd` code page to `UTF-8` by using `chcp 65001` command; 3. `powershell`; 4. in Powershell prompt, check `$PSSessionOption.UseUTF16` should return `False`; 5. (optional) check `$OutputEncoding` and `[console]::OutputEncoding`; 6. Use `$OutputEncoding=[console]::OutputEncoding`; 7. (optional) check `$OutputEncoding` again. Now, connect to _Debian_. If above workaround would help then we could find a more effectual procedure for you.

Comment: Maybe an one-liner `$OutputEncoding=[System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8` in Powershell console could suffice. Please forget all my previous comment: I'm learning powershell hardly and not easy…

Comment: This looks good. But still `npm install ...` gives me rubbish like `â""â"?â"?` instead of the tree view